# Preg replace till dot including that

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I am having one line I have to replace that below is the line

```
/myhome/ishere/where/are.you.ha
```

Here I have a live regex

```
preg_match('/(.+\/)[^.]+(.+\.ha)/', $input_line, $output_array);
```

it results me live this

```
/myhome/ishere/where/.you.ha
```

But I need a answer like this

```
/myhome/ishere/where/you.ha
```

Please anyone help me to remove this dot.

Comment: `preg_match()` can only match a contiguous substring. How is it giving you that match? Is that supposed to be `$output_array[0] . $output_array[1]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```php
/^(.+\/)[^.]*\.(.*\.ha)$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CpnGHO/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(.+\/)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then `/`
- `[^.]*` - zero or more chars other than a `.`
- `\.` - a `.` char
- `(.*\.ha)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then `.ha`
- `$` - end of a string

Answer (score 3):

You could write the pattern as this, which will give you 2 capture groups that you can use:

```
(.+\/)[^.]+\.([^.]+\.ha)$
```

**Explanation**

- `(.+\/)` Capture group 1, match 1+ chars and then the last `/`
- `[^.]+` Match 1+ non dots
- `\.` Match a dot
- `([^.]+\.ha)` Match non dots, then `.ha`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nThJzI/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/EGvXK)

If you use `$1$2` in the replacement:

```
$pattern = "/(.+\/)[^.]+\.([^.]+\.ha)$/";
$s = "/myhome/ishere/where/are.you.ha";
echo preg_replace($pattern, "$1$2", $s);
```

Output

```
/myhome/ishere/where/you.ha
```

Or see [a code an example](https://3v4l.org/bkV8q) using preg_match with 2 capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

Although I got the answer I was mistaking to put `+\.` in between

```
(.+/)[^.]+\.(.+\.ha)
```

```
preg_replace('/(.+\/)[^.]+\.(.+\.ha)/', '$1$2', $input_lines);
```

This is how it works.

Comment: If you got an answer, upvote and accept it, do not post another.